# Redux and Context API use together in same React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

Can we use Redux and Context API in the same React Native project? Is there any way or is there any issue if we use them together?

Actually, I want to implement authentication with the Context API and for other state management I want to use Redux Toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use both in a project but unnecessary. You can experience the simple part of redux with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) in React. [This document](https://www.codehousegroup.com/insight-and-inspiration/tech-stream/using-redux-and-context-api) explains this.
It uses Provider to keep context API and redux states. In your case, this will probably be the case.
follow this code:

```
<Provider store={reduxStore}>
 <Context.Provider value={contextValue}>
  <App/>
 </Context.Provider>
</Provider>
```